# How to configure List<?> type in hazelcast-client.xml for custom Byte array serialization

Tags: hazelcast, java-custom-serialization

I have created a custom serialization class using ByteArraySerializer as follows.

```
public class ProgramListSerializer implements ByteArraySerializer<List<Program>> {
public static final TypeReference<List<Program>> LIST_PROGRAM_TYPE = new TypeReference<List<Program>>() {};

private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());

public ProgramListSerializer() {
}

public int getTypeId() {
    return 1001;
}

public byte[] write(List<Program> object) throws IOException {
    return this.mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
}

public List<Program> read(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
    return this.mapper.readValue(buffer, LIST_PROGRAM_TYPE);
}

public void destroy() {
}}
```

Now I need to configure this in hazelcast-client.xml.I have tried to define as follows.

```
<serialization>
<serializers>
  <serializer class-name="com.XXX.serializer.ProgramListSerailizer" type-class="java.util.List&lt;com.xxx.Program&gt;"/>
</serializers>
```

Hazelcast unable recognise the class. Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.List

Is there any way to define type-class in hazelcast-client.xml for collections(List,Set) with generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the escape characters are rendering correctly, it should be

```
"&lt;" = "<"
"&gt;" = ">"
```

Comment: Sorry, It solves the compilation issue, but Hazelcast unable recognise the class. Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.List<com.xxx,.Program>

Comment: Our class loader com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil does not support java.util.List type directly (it supports ArrayList) and delegates to the default classLoader which does not support parameterized type in URLClassLoader.findClass().  Have you thought about wrapping the List with a serializable POJO?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with wrapping the List with a serializable POJO, it works well, but the disadvantage is we need to write a separate wrapper for each List<?> type. I have also tried with default com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ArrayListStreamSerializer without writing any wrapper or any custom serializer for List type. It seems Hazeltcast will handle automatically If you have already had custom serializer for your POJO.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the downside.  As you've discovered, Hazelcast will handle this automatically.  If you'd like  to further optimize, have Program class implement DataSerializable.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing if your definition will load correctly, you can fix your definition by properly escaping the "<" and ">" characters:

"<" = "<"
">" = ">"

as such:

type-class="java.util.List<com.xxx.Program>"